# Cannot Ping Site but DNS Resolves

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ping

I am using DNS-crypt proxy as a local DNS server with `cloudflare` as the resolver.

For some reason I cannot ping `www.automaticwebforms.com` despite the DNS resolving:

ping

```
$ ping www.automaticwebforms.com
ping: www.automaticwebforms.com: Name or service not known
```

netcat

```
$ netcat www.automaticwebforms.com 80                                                                                                                                                                                    
Error: Couldn't resolve host "www.automaticwebforms.com"
```

DNS

```
nslookup -debug www.automaticwebforms.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.automaticwebforms.com       canonical name = automaticwebforms.com.
Name:   automaticwebforms.com
Address: 198.50.128.113
```

host

```
host www.automaticwebforms.com
www.automaticwebforms.com is an alias for automaticwebforms.com.
automaticwebforms.com has address 198.50.128.113
automaticwebforms.com mail is handled by 10 mail.automaticwebforms.com.
```

`www.google.com` works fine for all of the services above.

Comment: It's entirely possible that ICMP traffic is blocked somewhere along the route to that host.  Have you tried TCPing or netcat on a known-open port?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Can't netcat either: `netcat www.automaticwebforms.com 80
Error: Couldn't resolve host "www.automaticwebforms.com"` (it's a website so presumably port 80 is open)

Comment: Cloudflare is resolving it now. Transient problem?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No same issue still.

Comment: I am solving it here in Portugal via cloudfare DNS and via dnscrypt with Cisco OpenDNS. Routing issues in your part of the world?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro seems like it does resolve but somewhere there is a disconnect when trying with applications

Comment: Maybe negative cache on your side. Worked well here

Comment: `nslookup` and `host` are resolvers themselves, the rest of the commands use the system's resolver, which is configured by `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (check if hosts: line has dns in it) and `/etc/resolv.conf` (check that contains valid nameservers).

Comment: See http://dnsviz.net/d/www.automaticwebforms.com/Wu9hjQ/dnssec/ there is a lame delegation for this domain.

Comment: @forcefsck Seems like `nslookup` and `dig` are using the settings in `resolv.conf` since they are both using `127.0.0.1:53` as their DNS servers which is the local instance of `dnscrypt-proxy`. Not sure if they use `nsswitch.conf`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'm not familiar with lame delegations. Would that cause it not to resolve for applications but allow it to resolve for `nslookup` and `dig`?

Comment: The parent and the child disagree on who are the authoritative nameservers for the zone. This creates a whole lot of breakage and there is no incentive to debug it further until this point is resolved. Parent says the nameservers are `ns1.exponenciel.com` and `ns2.exponenciel.com`.  And these 2 nameservers say the only one authoritative nameserver on the zone is `ns.automaticwebforms.com`. Since even more it is in-bailiwick and without glue there is no chance this DNS setup will work.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Okay so it's an error on their end. Thanks for the information! If you post that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

`ping(1)` checks *network* connectivity (it sends an ICMP ECHO-REQUEST to the target, and waits for a response; be aware that some totally clueless network "administrators" block ICMP and you won't get answers even if the host is reachable).

DNS (i.e. `host(1)` or `dig(1)` results) checks if the nameserver for the hostname is reachable and answers.

They are totally separate, the nameserver will typically run on some different machine, and the RFCs even demand that a copy of the data is kept on at least two servers on different networks. So the host can be down, or otherwise be unreachable, while DNS answers. Or the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is strange to me is that ping cannot even resolve the IP address of the website (which I assume it has to do through DNS) while dig returns the valid IP address fetched through DNS. I would expect that if the host is down that at least it would attempt to ping the IP address but would not receive any ping responses.